# Move item to bottom of listView on click

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I'm having a hard time figuring this one out, I need to be able to click on an item of a listview, and move that item to the bottom of the list with some background color change to make a difference, then if clicked back return it to the original position in the list.

I've tried with list.addFooterView() but I can't make it work that way, it just attach an empty item to the footer, I couldn't make it go back to it's original position.

Here is my code so far. Any ideas on how to tackle this are appreciated.

ActivityProductsBuy.java

```
package com.roneskinder;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.DatabaseUtils;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Matrix;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.roneskinder.model.DataProducts;
import com.roneskinder.utils.DatabaseHandler;
import com.roneskinder.x111.R;

public class ActivityProductsBuy extends Activity {

    protected Context mContext;

    protected DatabaseHandler db;
    private SQLiteDatabase newDB;
    private String tableProducts = DatabaseHandler.TABLE_PRODUCTS;

    protected ListView lvProducts;
    protected String title, idProduct, idGroceryList, ProductCode, ProductName;
    protected int totalItems, itemsInCart = 0;
    protected Button btn_itemsInCart;
    protected TextView tv_percentText;

    /** The data used for products */
    private List<DataProducts> info;

    /** The Adapter holds the listview. */
    private ProductsItemAdapter adapter1;

    private static final int ZBAR_SCANNER_REQUEST = 0;

    protected SharedPreferences preferences;

    protected String TAG = ActivityProductsBuy.class.getName();

    ImageView imgHolder;
    Paint paint;
    EditText edtPercentage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_products_buy);

        mContext = getApplicationContext();

        // Get Database values for User
        db = new DatabaseHandler(mContext);

        preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        // remove and add products to DB
        //db.removeAllProducts();
        // this.addProducts();

        // get intent Extras (the title, list id)
        //title = getIntent().getExtras().getString("title");
        idGroceryList = getIntent().getExtras().getString("idGroceryList");

        lvProducts = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lvProducts);

        info = new ArrayList<DataProducts>();
        imgHolder = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.coringImage);
        btn_itemsInCart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_itemsInCart);
        tv_percentText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.percentText);
        tv_percentText.setText("0%");

        paint = new Paint();

        adapter1 = new ProductsItemAdapter(this, info);

        // load all database products into listview
        lvProducts.setAdapter(adapter1);
        loadProducts();
        totalItems = adapter1.getCount();

        lvProducts.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                itemsInCart++;
                if(itemsInCart <= totalItems){
                    btn_itemsInCart.setText("(" + itemsInCart + "/"+ totalItems +")");
                    // Fill percentage of image
                    float percentage = ((float)itemsInCart/(float)totalItems)*100;
                    Log.d(TAG, "percentage: " + percentage);
                    imgHolder.setImageResource(R.drawable.cart_default);

                    if (percentage > 0 && percentage <= 100) {
                        imgHolder.setImageBitmap(doBottomToTopOperation(Math.round(percentage)));
                        tv_percentText.setText((int)percentage + "%");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void loadProducts() {
        info.clear();
        ((BaseAdapter) lvProducts.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
        Cursor cur = null;
        try {
            newDB = db.getWritableDatabase();
            cur = newDB.rawQuery(
                    "SELECT idProduct, ProductCode, name FROM "
                            + tableProducts + " WHERE idGroceryList = " + idGroceryList, null);

            Log.d(TAG, DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cur));

            if (cur != null) {
                // tvNoProducts.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                if (cur.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        idProduct = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("idProduct"));
                        ProductCode = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("ProductCode"));
                        ProductName = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex("name"));

                        info.add(new DataProducts(ProductName, ProductCode,idProduct, "Vegetales", "0", idGroceryList));
                    } while (cur.moveToNext());
                }
            } else {
                // tvNoProducts.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        } catch (SQLiteException se) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(),
                    "Could not create or Open the database");
        }

    }

    /**
     * The Class ProductsItemAdapter.
     */
    private class ProductsItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        /** The context. */
        private Context context;

        /** The list. */
        private List<DataProducts> list;

        /** The inflater. */
        private LayoutInflater inflater;

        /**
         * Instantiates a new deal item adapter.
         * 
         * @param context
         *            the context
         * @param list
         *            the list
         */
        public ProductsItemAdapter(Context context, List<DataProducts> list) {
            this.context = context;
            this.list = list;
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see android.widget.Adapter#getCount()
         */
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return list.size();
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see android.widget.Adapter#getItem(int)
         */
        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see android.widget.Adapter#getItemId(int)
         */
        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return 0;
        }

        /*
         * (non-Javadoc)
         * 
         * @see android.widget.Adapter#getView(int, android.view.View,
         * android.view.ViewGroup)
         */
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            if (convertView == null) {
                inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_products, null);
            }
            TextView txt1 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvProductName);
            TextView txt2 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvProductCode);
            TextView tv1 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvProductPrice);
            TextView tv2 = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.tvProductCategory);

            final DataProducts dInfo = list.get(position);
            txt1.setText(dInfo.getProductName());
            txt2.setText(dInfo.getProductCode());

            tv1.setText(dInfo.getProductPrice());
            // tv1.setPaintFlags(tv1.getPaintFlags() |
            // Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);

            tv2.setText(dInfo.getProductCategory());
            return convertView;
        }

    }

    public Bitmap doBottomToTopOperation(int percentage) {
        Bitmap bitmapOriginal = ((BitmapDrawable) imgHolder.getDrawable()).getBitmap();

        Bitmap bitmapTarget = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.cart_filled);

        int heightToCrop = bitmapTarget.getHeight() * (100 - percentage) / 100;

        Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapTarget, 0, heightToCrop, bitmapTarget.getWidth(), bitmapTarget.getHeight() - heightToCrop);

        Bitmap bmOverlay = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOriginal.getWidth(),
                bitmapOriginal.getHeight(), bitmapOriginal.getConfig());
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmOverlay);
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmapOriginal, new Matrix(), null);
        canvas.drawBitmap(croppedBitmap,
                canvas.getWidth() - croppedBitmap.getWidth(),
                canvas.getHeight() - croppedBitmap.getHeight(), null);

        return bmOverlay;
    }

}
```

activity_products_buy.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout
        xmlns:sothree="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/sliding_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        sothree:umanoPanelHeight="68dp"
        sothree:umanoShadowHeight="4dp" >

        <!-- MAIN LAYOUT -->

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/lvProducts"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@+id/myFilter" >
        </ListView>

        <!-- SLIDING LAYOUT -->

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/dragView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="250dp"
            android:background="#ffffff"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="68dp"
                android:background="#f0f0f0"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/name"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:text="Total de Productos en el carrito"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_itemsInCart"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical|right"
                    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                    android:paddingRight="10dp"
                    android:text="(0)"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:textSize="14sp" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/coringImage"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:src="@drawable/cart_default" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/percentText"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/coringImage"
                    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/coringImage"
                    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/coringImage"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/coringImage"
                    android:layout_margin="1dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:text="0%"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

adapter_products.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/top"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/pad_10dp"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/pad_10dp"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/pad_15dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/left_layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/pad_10dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_mypurchase1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/pad_10dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/right_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvProductName"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Nombre del Producto" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvProductCode"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:paddingTop="@dimen/pad_2.5dp"
                    android:text="Codigo" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvProductPrice"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="@string/$45"
                    android:textColor="@color/red_main"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_18sp" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvProductCategory"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Categoria"
                    android:textSize="@dimen/txt_12sp" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/pad_15dp"
            android:background="@color/my_purchase_list_sap" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change index of the item in your data source, and then `notifyDataSetChanged()`

```
DataProducts item = info.get(<index>);
info.remove(<index>);
info.add(item);
adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Set background for the bottom item in `getView`,

```
if (position==getCount()-1){
    convertView.setBackground(<backgroud>);
}
```

If you want move it back,

```
DataProducts item = info.get(info.size()-1);
info.remove(info.size()-1);
info.add(<original_index>,item);
adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Makes sense, but how can i change the background color of that item in the bottom?

Comment: Worked like a charm for one item, how do i make this for every item in the list? the idea is in one point all are going to be with different background and in the bottom

Comment: im not so clear what's ur point, but if you want set different backgroud for different items, then it's better make an ArrayList to store all the corresponding background for every item. after that, use `convertView.setBackground(ArrayList.get(position))`